# How to find out if I have installed a Python module in Linux?

Tags: python, import, module, installation

I tried to install a Python module by typing: sudo python setup.py install
After I typed this command I got a lot of output to the screen.
The lest few lines are bellow:

```
writing manifest file 'scikits.audiolab.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
removing '/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/scikits.audiolab-0.10.2-py2.5.egg-info' (and everything under it)
Copying scikits.audiolab.egg-info to /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/scikits.audiolab-0.10.2-py2.5.egg-info
Installing /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/scikits.audiolab-0.10.2-py2.5-nspkg.pth
running install_scripts
```

So, there were nothing suspicious. But when I tried to use the module from the Python:

```
import pyaudiolab
```

I see that Python does not find the module:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyaudiolab ImportError: No module named pyaudiolab
```

How can I found out what went wrong? As a result of the installation I get a new directory:
/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages (so something happened) but I still cannot use the module. Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried `import scikits.audiolab` or `import audiolab`?

Comment: I just tried what you have suggested. "audiolab" instead "pyaudiolab" does not change anything. When I try import scikits.audiolab I get: File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/scikits/audiolab/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from numpy.testing import Tester

Comment: it seems you have dependency on a module named Tester which you dont have (regarding the reproted problem it seems like it is solved)

Answer (score 1):

From the OP's comment to an answer, it's clear that `scikits.audiolab` is indeed where this module's been installed, but it also needs you to install `numpy`.  Assuming the module's configuration files are correct, by using `easy_install` instead of the usual `python setup.py` run, you might have automatically gotten and installed such extra dependencies -- that's one of the main points of `easy_install` after all.  But you can also do it "manually" (for better control of where you get dependencies from and exactly how you install them), of course -- however, in that case, you do need to check and manually install the dependencies, too.

Comment: I have installed numpy before. And it works fine (if I type "from numpy import *", Python does not complain.

Comment: @Roman, so can you `import numpy.testing`? What about `from numpy.testing import Tester`?  Looks like you have an older (what version?) or partially-installed `numpy` that doesn't supply the `testing` sub-module or its `Tester`, and scikits.audiolab requires that.

Comment: I can "import numpy.testing" but I cannot "from numpy.testing import Tester". Version of numpy is '1.1.1'.

Comment: When I type "sudo apt-get install python-numpy" I get the following message "python-numpy is already the newest version". But as far as I know 1.1.1. is not the latest version of the numpy. How it comes?

Comment: 1.1.1 is not the latest upstream numpy, but it may be the latest supported by your version of Ubuntu (or Debian or whatever other Linux distro you have).

Answer (score 1):

Your library depends upon numoy. Try installing numpy:

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy
```

Comment: When I type what suggested, the system says me that I have already the newest version of numpy. And Python says that my version of numpy is 1.1.1. which, as far as I know, is NOT the latest version. I think it is an old version which does not contain "Tester" that I need.

Answer (score 1):

You need a more recent version of numpy (>= 1.2.0), as indicated on the audiolab installation informations.

Answer (score 0):

- check if you have the module somewhere inside:
  /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/
  (search for a file named |modulename|.py so in your example - try: pyaudiolab.py or audiolab.py)
- if it exists - check if the directory in which it exists is found in the sys.path variable:

  import sys

  sys.path

Comment: I do not have *audiolab.py in /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/. But I have there a directory called scikits.audiolab-0.10.2-py2.5.egg-info. But this subdirectory also does not contain *audiolab.py file.

Comment: try importing the following:
from numpy.testing import Tester
this seems to be your current problem